# onSubmitEditing: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: react-native

There is a textinput in my screen. Besides that there is a search icon. Upon pressing the search icon, this.searchmethod() is called and searching is performed. I also want to perform searching upon pressing the "search", "done", "go" or "enter" button of the keyboard. I tried onSubmitEditing like shown in below, which resulted in the error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded
> My code:

```
<TextInput 
    onChangeText = {
    text => {
        this.setState({
            searchtag: text
        })
    }
}
    onSubmitEditing={this.searchmethod()}
    onFocus = {() => {
        if (this.state.searchtag != "")
            this.setState({
                searchtag: ''
            }, () => {
                this._refreshData()
            })
    }
}
/> 
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress = {
        () => {
            this.searchmethod()
        }
    } >
    <View>
        <FearIcon name = "search" size = {25}/> 
    </View> 
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Kindly guide me how I can perform searching upon pressing "done" or etc key on Keyboard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
onSubmitEditing={() => this.searchmethod()}
```

Instead of onFocus, refreshData in onChangeText like

```
this.setState({
            searchtag: text
        },
     () => this._refreshData();
)
```